# How do i build a hierarchical database with apache Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra

I want to develop a hierarchical database to store **directory structure** in the filesystem.

Just like

```
 Root
   -dir
     -subdir
     -subdir
        -subdir
            -subdir
            -subdir
     -subdir
     -subdir
```

can i use Apache Cassandra for this

a java example will be better to understand.

Comment: In the most technical sense, yes this is possible. Each row could have a column named "parent". However traversing the tree (like almost all iteration operations in cassandra) would be terribly slow and inefficient.

Comment: thanks. can you give a example to make it more clear please.

Comment: +1 I was searching for the exact term to call this parent kind of database relationship, didn't know it is called hierarchical database structure.

Comment: Refer http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ , given approaches are good enough in terms of Storing data .but quite slow in term of retrieval

Comment: Wikipedia also provides a good overview at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model (see also links to alternatives such as nested intervals).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could store the data, type and parent of a path in a column family,

```
paths { #colum family 
    "/some/path" { # key
         "type" : "file|directory" #column, either file or directory, if this is a file or a directory
         "data" : "??" # if this is a file, the data for the file.  you don't want to be storing very large files in cassandra in one column
    }
}
```

With cassandra, you need to denormalize to serve the queries you are going to perform.  You probably want to query the children of a directory, so have a structure like,

```
children { #column family 
    "/some/path" { # key
         "child-path-1" : null #column, one for each child of /some/path
         "child-path-2" : null 
    }
}
```

Add more column families to support the other queries you wish to do.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is what i would do for a relational dbms schema.

```
product{
  id int,
  parent_id int,
  name varchar2(30)
}
```

Sample data:

```
product
--------------------
id   | parent_id   | name
0    | 0           | root
1    | 0           | laptop
2    | 0           | pc
3    | 1           | Dell Latitude E4310
4    | 1           | Dell Vostro E3300
5    | 2           | Compaq Desktop 3
6    | 2           | Compaq Presario 2
```

Comment: +1 For the Example. Actually this is the great idea for implementing hierarchical data in RDBMS. But i think it requires though programming to implement such structure. Suppose if we delete the root then we have to write the code to delete all the descendants. Please correct if i am wrong.

Comment: How do you know that an item is file  or directory?